# Vector type inside fgets

Tags: c++, c, file, vector, dynamic-arrays

I have this theory, I can grab the file size using fseek and ftell and build a dynamic array as a buffer. Then use the buffer for fgets(). I currently can not come up with a way to do it.

My theory is based off of not knowing the size of the first file in bytes. So, I do not know how big of a buffer to build. What if the file is over 2 gigs? I want to be able to build a buffer that will change and recognize the file size of whatever file I put into SearchInFile().

Here is what I have so far below:

```
int SearchInFile(char *fname, char *fname2)
{
    FILE *pFile, *pFile2;
    int szFile, szFile2;

    // Open first file
    if( (fopen_s(&pFile, fname, "r")) != NULL )
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    // Open second file
    if( (fopen_s(&pFile2, fname2, "r")) != NULL )
    {
        return(-1);
    }

    // Find file size 
    fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    szFile = ftell(pFile);
    // Readjust File Pointer
    fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    std::vector <char> buff;
    //char buff[szFile];

    while(fgets(buff.push_back(), szFile, pFile))
    {


    }
```

Any thoughts or examples would be great. I've been searching the net for the last few hours.

Comment: Does `fopen_s` really return `NULL` on success?

Comment: Why are you using old C-style standard I/O instead of C++ streams?

Comment: Also, if you have very large files, you should consider memory mapping them instead.

Comment: Can you link me to an example Joachim?

Comment: For POSIX platforms (like Linux and OSX) you have [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html). For Windows see e.g. [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector can grow, so you don't have to know the size beforehand. The following four lines do what you want.

```
std::vector<char> buff;
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(pFile)) != EOF)
    buff.push_back(ch);
```

`fgetc` is a function to read a single char, simpler than using `fgets`.

If you do know the file size beforehand then you could call `buff.reserve(szFile)` before the loop. This will make the loop a little more efficient.

Comment: This is the worst possible way to do it - reading a large file byte-by-byte will be very slow. Plus you will get lots of vector reallocations which, again, will slow down the reading process. Large files should be read using larger data blocks.

Comment: @jimvonmoon Firstly the file is buffered, so it will be read in large data blocks. Secondly my advice to use reserve deals with the reallocation of the vector. Thirdly maybe efficiency isn't the poster's top concern. When you say 'the worst' you are making a subjective statement as if it was an objective statement.

Comment: @john It's not all about file being buffered or not, but about calling `fgetc` (which is a system call) insane amount of times.

Comment: OK, well compilers are perfectly capable of optimizing a call to `fgetc` so that it is inlined. But if that isn't good enough then use `getc` instead of `fgetc`. Since `getc` is a macro it's bound to be inlined. In any case I'll repeat what I said earlier, 'efficiency' isn't the only consideration.